returning a pdf (TCPDF) with a laravel api
I am moving a laravel app to a laravel api and I have a functionality to create pdfs with TCPDF in the laravel app it works without any problem but when I try to move this functionality to an api I am getting several errors.

the pdf comes empty (this should not be happenning)

the pdf comes without the name (it seems to be)
//laravel controller code: 

 $filename = $odp_volumetrica->codigo . ' L ' . $odp_volumetrica->lote . '.pdf';
 $filename = str_replace(' ', '_', $filename); 

 header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
 header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' . $filename . '"');
 header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
 $pdf->Output($filename, 'I'); 


//react client code:
     authorizedRequest
     .get('/odps/13/printCoa')
     .then(({ data }) => {
         const blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'application/pdf' });
         window.open(URL.createObjectURL(blob));
     })
     .catch((error) => {
         console.log(error);
     });



I would like to know if there is a way to return these pdfs and open them in a new tab in the browser and if possible its name is not a random string.

Have you tried?
const link = document.createElement('a');
link.download = 'your-name.pdf';
link.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob));
link.click();

